# SQLAlchemy and message consumer- where session should be placed?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, message-queue, messaging

Can't find any example how to use `Session()` object with consumers. In SQLAlchemy documentation there is told how to deal with web applications, daemon processes, however there is no information how to deal with consumers.
My code looks like this:

```
        engine_1 = create_engine(
            'connection_string',
            pool_pre_ping=True,
            pool_size=5,
            pool_recycle=3600,
            max_overflow=5,
        )

        engine_2 = create_engine(
            'connection_string',
            pool_pre_ping=True,
            pool_size=5,
            pool_recycle=3600,
            max_overflow=5,
        )
```

I have two engines to two different databases.
Here is my consumer's code:

```
    db_session_1 = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine_1)
    db_session_2 = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine_2)
    msg_processor = MessageProcessor(db_session_1, db_session_2)

    for message in consumer: # <--- consumer it's a KafkaConsumer object. It's a permanent loop
        try:
            msg_processor.process(message)
        except Exception as err:
            logger.error(err)
```

And here is a `MessageProcessor` class:

```
class MessageProcessor:
    def __init__(self, session_1, session_2):
        self.user = UserService(session_1)
        self.address = AddressService(session_1, session_2)

    def process(self, message):
        try:
            values = json.loads(message.value)
            self.user.do_something(values)
            self.address.do_something(values)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
```

The problem is that if there is a delay between messages. One or two minutes. Next message which come will generate error because of lost connection to databases.

```
2022-03-17 13:50:13,540 INFO sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Invalidate connection <pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x7fd9098486a0> (reason: OperationalError:(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'))
2022-03-17 13:50:13,540 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Closing connection <pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x7fd9098486a0>
ERROR:root:(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
[SQL: {sql from UserService.do_something(values)}]
```

And it happens every time! It looks like `Session()` object from SQLAlchemy can't revalidate connection to database before commiting transaction. So the question is:
**How should I connect to database in process which is permanently running and waiting for messages coming from Kafka Broker?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused about your [sessionmaker](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker) usage.  Usually it is used like `Session = sessionmaker()` to get a session maker (or session factory)... then later you make a single session like `session = Session()`.  I don't see the second step.

I would make a separate session using the session makers in each iteration like this:

```py
for message in consumer:
    with db_session_1() as session_1, db_session_2() as session_2:
        msg_processor = MessageProcessor(session_1(), session_2())
        try:
            msg_processor.process(message)
        except Exception as err:
            logger.error(err)
```

**This is using sqlalchemy 1.4.**

Comment: Won't it have any impact on the performance? As far as I understand `with db_session_1() as session_1, db_session_2() as session_2:` means that during each iteration it will connect to database and close connection

Comment: The engine should handle the connection pool.  When the session ends then the connection should be returned to the pool.  As I understand it.  So you are creating and destroying a session but not necessarily a connection.  By placing the session in the context manager You can make sure that the session is cleaned up and the connection will be returned properly for the engine pool to deal with.  Note: If you are using transactions then you will have to call commit manually the way this context manager is set up.